# Increase number of tests/sec in Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Load Test

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

I have created a Visual Studio Load Test to see how my site behaves under load. I have set up a number of virtual users (I've tried 50, 250 and 1000) and configured to not use think times to really hammer the site. However, each virtual user seems to make a request and get a response (usually in less than 0.2 seconds), then wait for the other users to finish their requests before issuing a new request. This gives a pretty constant of around 55 tests/sec - the same if I have 50 or 1000 virtual users. I have tried recreating the test several times and use settings out-of-the-box but still cannot get higher throughput. Is there a setting somewhere I am missing out here or what? I was thinking 250 users could issue 250 simultaneous requests and not seemingly wait for each other to finish.

Comment: are you sure it's related to load testing or not your web site ?

Comment: I considered that but each virtual user seems to not do anything between requests. The graph shows a request and a response and then seconds (nothing) before next request. I turned think times off so I'm  sort of at a loss here.